# SQL validator for Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, software-development, validation

I am looking for an SQL validator / Syntax Checker which can be executed via CLI.

Must-haves:

- Be able to check an SQL command for errors and return the error(s) if any
- [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis)
- Executable on [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) (locally, no web connection)

Nice to have:

- [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source)
- Python interface, e.g. having a python function which can lint an SQL string
- Allow different SQL dialects
- Active developers

Comment: Are there any SQL dialects that are mandatory – like "must support Oracle and MySQL dialects"? Not that I have anything in mind – but wouldn't it be nasty if the one most important to you were missing? ;) Apart from that: +1 :)

Comment: I'm not sure ... I use snowflake warehouse, mysql and postgres. But for this question, I would be fine with a validator which deals with standard SQL

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, my program [sql-lint](https://github.com/joereynolds/sql-lint/tree/typescript/src) will do what you need.

It is open source, completely free and in active development. Linting a query is as simple as:

```
echo "DELETE FROM person;" | sql-lint
```

It will bring back errors from the SQL server and its own built-in ones.

Hope that helps, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at sql-lint: https://github.com/joereynolds/sql-lint

I don't have any personal experience with it, but it appears to meet your requirements for a command-line interface, error reporting, and support for both MySQL and Postgres.